# How can I set an inline style in React?

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to set an inline style in React:

```
<div className="lemma" style={{color: 'red'}}>{r.lemma}</div>
```

However, the `class` attribute is rendered, while the style is not:

[image]

How do I get the style to render? [Here's a link to my project on GitHub](https://github.com/morpher-ru/gramdict/blob/master/gramdictru/Scripts/ResultsBox/index.tsx#L28)

Comment: This is the correct syntax. Probably you need to either rebuild your .tsx file or clear your browser cache.

Comment: Ah! One of the two hard problems in programming. How could I forget! Thank you!